# Rxjs repeatwhen with delay

Tags: angular, rxjs

There is something I don't understand using repeatWhen and delay()

I reproduce my problem on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cbdeu7

You need to open the console.

i use takeWhile to end the repeatWhen stream so that it should not go through the delay operator.

but the 10 seconds delay is still applied before logging 'complete event' in the subscribe.

Why?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I am assuming whoever did did so because you just posted a link and some instructions, which is not considered a good question here on SO. Please edit your question to include a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Why would the `takeWhile` prevent the delay?  Both are in the pipe.  So the inputs are piped through all three of your methods; the takeWhile, the delay, and the take 2

Comment: I change the isDone value before so takewhile should complete the stream. If i replace delay(10000) with mergeMap(() => timer(10000)) I get the expected behavior complete is called directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let isDone = false;
this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2').pipe(
  tap(() => isDone = true), 
  repeatWhen(
    (s) => s.pipe(takeWhile(() => !isDone), delay(10000), take(2))
  )
).subscribe(
  (e) => console.log('next', e),
  err => {}, 
  () => console.log('why complete after 10s ?');
);
```

Let's see what the flow would be.

- `this.http.get()` will emit a value and then a `complete` notification; when the value has been emitted, `isDone` becomes `true` and you should see the results of `console.log('next', e)`.
- the `complete` notification will be intercepted by `repeatWhen`, which internally uses a `Subject` in order to notify about such notifications. `s.pipe(takeWhile(() => !isDone), delay(10000), take(2))` will eventually become a subscriber of that subject; so, when that subject emits, all of its registered subscribers will receive that value(`next` notification), but because `() => !isDone` returns `false`, `takeWhile` will immediately send a `complete` notification
- now it is the important part; let's see how [`delay` handles](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.x/src/internal/operators/delay.ts#L151-L155) a `complete` notification:

```js
protected _complete() {
  this.scheduleNotification(Notification.createComplete());
  this.unsubscribe();
}
```

What `this.scheduleNotification` does is to schedule a task to be done in `10s`(your `delay` value), and that task is to send that `complete` notification(from `takeWhile`).

Note that the above snippet is from RxJs `6.5.5`. In version `7.x`, it should send the `complete` notification [as soon as possible](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/delay.ts#L143-L148):

```js
protected _complete() {
  if (this.queue.length === 0) {
    this.destination.complete();
  }
  this.unsubscribe();
}
```